# Подскажите способ отображения списка, пожалуйста

Tags: python, tkinter

Имеется какой-то список. Его нужно отобразить в окне. Каким способом я могу это сделать? Знаю, что есть tkinter.ListBox() , но он представлен как виджет предполагающий выбор, а мне необходимо просто красивое расположение списка по всему окну. 
Примечание. В список будут добавляться новые элементы пользователем
Буду благодарен, если поможете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если `Listbox()` недостаточно, вариантов много может быть в зависимости от задачи, к примеру, у [`ttk.Treeview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#treeview) есть множество опций, но можно и для простого списка использовать:

[image: tkinter treeview list]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from tkinter import Tk, ttk

spells = ['Accio', 'Alohomora', 'Expecto Patronum', 'Expelliarmus']
title = 'Spells'

root = Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=[title], height=len(spells),
                    show="headings", selectmode='none')
tree.heading('#1', text=title)
for item in spells:
    tree.insert('', 'end', values=(item,))
tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Может конечно глупо, но как вариант можно сделать `Label` и в него задавать значение каждый раз

```
import random
import tkinter


def func():
    c.append(random.random())
    label.config(text="\n".join(str(i) for i in c))


root = tkinter.Tk()
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
button = tkinter.Button(root, text='Нажми', command=func).pack()
label = tkinter.Label(root, text="\n".join(str(i) for i in c), justify=tkinter.LEFT)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]